# Error serializing struct: Expected struct JsValue, found Struct Error

Tags: rust, wasm-bindgen

I'm getting the error:

```
expected enum `std::result::Result<_, wasm_bindgen::JsValue>`
         found enum `std::result::Result<_, serde_wasm_bindgen::error::Error>`
```

when I serialize a struct by implementing Serialize then passing it to `serde_wasm_bindgen`, which uses the example code from [here](https://docs.serde.rs/serde/trait.Serialize.html)
here is the min reproducable code:

```rust
use wasm_bindgen::prelude::*;
use serde::ser::{Serialize, SerializeStruct, Serializer};

struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u8,
    phones: Vec<String>,
}
impl Serialize for Person {
    fn serialize<S>(&self, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let mut s = serializer.serialize_struct("Person", 3)?;
        s.serialize_field("name", &self.name)?;
        s.serialize_field("age", &self.age)?;
        s.serialize_field("phones", &self.phones)?;
        s.end()
    }
}

#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn pass_value_to_js() -> Result<JsValue, JsValue> {
    let p = Person {
        name: String::from("Hello"),
        age: 56,
        phones: vec![String::from("phone")],
    };
    serde_wasm_bindgen::to_value(p) // error here
}
```

Cargo.toml

```
serde-wasm-bindgen = "0.1.3"
serde = "1.0.114"
```

Comment: I don't know anything about these packages, but it appears that [to_value](https://github.com/cloudflare/serde-wasm-bindgen/blob/dabac188834e155c178620a172389a164488b77a/src/lib.rs) doesn't have a return type compatible with `Result<JsValue, JsValue>`.  It looks like you maybe want `Result<JsValue, Error>`?

Comment: @asm I think you're exactly right. The file you linked shows that the return type of `to_value<T>()` is `Result<T, serde_wasm_bindgen::Error>`. Maybe consider posting that as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed [this issue](https://github.com/cloudflare/serde-wasm-bindgen/issues/6) to solve the problem.

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn pass_value_to_js() -> Result<JsValue, JsValue> {
    serde_wasm_bindgen::to_value(&value).map_err(|err| err.into())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about these packages, but looking at the code for `to_value` [here](https://github.com/cloudflare/serde-wasm-bindgen/blob/dabac188834e155c178620a172389a164488b77a/src/lib.rs) it appears that the result is not compatible with `Result<JsValue, JsValue>`.

```rust
// The Error in scope here is serde_wasm_bindgen::error::Error
type Result<T> = std::result::Result<T, Error>;

...SNIP...

/// Converts a Rust value into a [`JsValue`].
pub fn to_value<T: serde::ser::Serialize>(value: &T) -> Result<JsValue> {
    value.serialize(&Serializer::new())
}
```

So it looks like the function you have returning this value must change to be compatible with this new `Result` type.

I'm guessing you are referring to the example in the README [here](https://github.com/cloudflare/serde-wasm-bindgen).  I very often find that code examples in github READMEs are incorrect or out of date.  Unfortunately I can't find an example or test in that repo that uses `to_value()` without immediately `unwrap()`ing it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up following the [an issue](https://github.com/cloudflare/serde-wasm-bindgen/issues/6), which worked for me

Comment: btw your solution worked for solving the immediate problem, but caused another problem with bindgen, where a trait wasn't implemented.